# Tiered Shipping based on cart subtotal in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

In Woocommerce, I need to set up shipping costs based on cart subtotal as following:

- if price is below 20€ the shipping cost is 5,90€,
- if price start from 20€ and below 30€ the shipping cost 4,90€
- if price start from 30€ and up the shipping cost 3,90€.

I have very basic PHP knowledge and have modified a code snippet that I have found.

This is my code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates','bbloomer_woocommerce_tiered_shipping', 10, 2 );
function bbloomer_woocommerce_tiered_shipping( $rates, $package){
    $threshold1 = 20;
    $threshold2 = 30;
    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < $threshold1 ){
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:5'] );
        unset($rates['flat_rate:6']);
    } elseif((WC()->cart->subtotal>$threshold1)and(WC()->cart->subtotal<$threshold2) ) {
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:6'] ); 
    } elseif((WC()->cart->subtotal > $threshold2) and (WC()->cart->subtotal > $threshold1) ) {
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:5'] );  
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

This seems to be working, but sometimes (and I have not figured out the trigger!) it doesn't and all three shipping methods show up in the cart. I think I noticed that it only happens when a user is logged in, but I am not 100% sure on this.

Is my function is correct? Do need to change or improve anything?

Comment: I don't know whats point of your question, by the way for solving your problem why are you unsetting value of arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have revisited your code a bit. You should try the following:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates','subtotal_based_tiered_shipping', 10, 2 );
function subtotal_based_tiered_shipping( $rates, $package ){
    $threshold1 = 20;
    $threshold2 = 30;
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    
    if ( $subtotal < $threshold1 ) 
    { // Below 20 ('flat_rate:1' is enabled)
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:5'] );
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:6'] );
    } 
    elseif ( $subtotal >= $threshold1 && $subtotal < $threshold2 ) 
    { // Starting from 20 and below 30 ('flat_rate:5' is enabled)
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:6'] ); 
    } 
    elseif ( $subtotal >= $threshold2 ) 
    { // Starting from 30 and up ('flat_rate:6' is enabled)
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:5'] );  
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

It should works now as intended.

> **To make it work with "Free shipping" methods too**, you will have to disable **"Free shipping requires..."** option *(set to **"N/A"**)*.

---

> **Sometimes you should need to refresh shipping caches:**
>
> Once saved this code and emptied cart, go to your shipping settings. In your shipping zone, disable save and re-enable save your shipping methods.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the detailed info  on the code. It's very helpful when learning PHP.